# How to find a pattern and surrounding content in a very large SINGLE line file?

Tags: parsing, bash

I have a very large file 100Mb+ where all the content is on one line.
I wish to find a pattern in that file and a number of characters around that pattern.

For example I would like to call a command like the one below but where -A and -B are number of bytes not lines:

```
cat very_large_file | grep -A 100 -B 100 somepattern
```

So for a file containing content like this:

```
1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

With a pattern of

```
890abc
and a before size of -B 3 
and an after size of -A 3
```

I want it to return:

```
567890abcdef
```

Any tips would be great.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try the -o option:

```
-o, --only-matching
      Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.
```

and use a regular expression to match your pattern and the 3 preceding/following characters i.e.

```
grep -o -P ".{3}pattern.{3}" very_large_file
```

In the example you gave, it would be

```
echo "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" > tmp.txt
grep -o -P ".{3}890abc.{3}" tmp.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, the correct option for regular expressions is -P, not -e

Answer (score 4):

Another one with *sed* (you may need it on systems where *GNU grep* is not available):

```
sed -n '
  s/.*\(...890abc...\).*/\1/p
  ' infile
```

Answer (score 3):

Best way I can think of doing this is with a tiny Perl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$pattern = $ARGV[0];
$before = $ARGV[1];
$after = $ARGV[2];

while(<>) {
  print $& if( /.{$before}$pattern.{$after}/ );
}
```

You would then execute it thusly:

```
cat very_large_file | ./myPerlScript.pl 890abc 3 3
```

**EDIT:** Dang, Paolo's solution is much easier. Oh well, viva la Perl!

Comment: Well, when one thinks of regular expressions, Perl is kind of the native language... guess what the -P in my grep line stands for :) ?